# Convert Key Value pairs to string

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the key value pairs from a csv file to a string and append them.

Link to the csv file: [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fIJKscFb75ZJiigb58Vmxx8Pe-MsiLqy)

I'm trying to format it like:
{"ABC":"43","DEF":"33"}
and store it as string.

This is basically appending the key value pairs for the Notes(Key) & year 1996(value)

Code snippet that I have tried:

```
fin=''
x=''
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("salesexample.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    #x=print('"'+str(row['Notes'])+'"',':'+'"'+str(row['1996'])+'",')
    for row in input_file:
        cont=str(row['Notes'])
        year=str(row['1996'])
        x=x+'"'+cont+'":'+'"'+year+'",'
    fin='{'+x+'}'
    print(fin)
```

But running the above code throws error like cant convert tuple to string.
Please help.

Comment: Notes and 1996 are column headers in csv files?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? It is working fine on Python 3

Comment: Are you able to use the `pandas` module?

Comment: @RajithThennakoon Yes

Comment: @MoosaSaadat Please try now... I have edited the code where it throw error.

Comment: @alan.elkin Yes I'm able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but for something like this I'd prefer to use Pandas.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("salesexample.csv")

cont = df['Notes'].to_list()
years = df.columns[1:].to_list()

for year in years:
    your_dict = {c:str(y) for (c,y) in zip(cont,df[year])}
    your_dict_string = f"{your_dict}" # optional, if you really need it to be a string
    print(f"{year} : {your_dict_string}")
```

This prints the following output:

```
1990 : {'ABC': '200', 'DEF': '11'}
1991 : {'ABC': '134', 'DEF': '9'}
1992 : {'ABC': '156', 'DEF': '12'}
1993 : {'ABC': '564', 'DEF': '-'}
1994 : {'ABC': '12', 'DEF': '12'}
1995 : {'ABC': '43', 'DEF': '67'}
1996 : {'ABC': '43', 'DEF': '33'}
```

Naturally, you could append each `your_dict`/`your_dict_string` variable into a list within the for loop for later use.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre... This one worked for me... :) Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested for loops. Only 1 loop is enough to get the desired results. Following code works in Python3:

```
fin=''
x=''
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("salesexample.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    #x=print('"'+str(row['Notes'])+'"',':'+'"'+str(row['1996'])+'",')
      cont=str(row['Notes'])
      year=str(row['1996'])
      x=x+'"'+cont+'":'+'"'+year+'",'
fin='{' + x
fin=fin[:-1] + '}'
print(fin)
```

**Output: `{"ABC":"43","DEF":"33"}`**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("salesexample.csv")
result = dict(zip(df["Notes"],df["1996"]))
```